# How to handle error for PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, try-catch, php-curl

I've done every bit of tips and answers but I can't seem to find the right solution.

my cURL is as follows

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $curlIP."api/sparts/search/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "key=".$q."&page=".$pg);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

**What does this do?**

It gets products data from a server where `$q` is the search key and `$pg` is the page number

This cURL works as intended assuming the server will always have an internet connection. As the developer we needed to have an error message whenever the cURL cannot connect to the server.

**What is the problem?**

For me to actually set an error message I need to know first if the error has happened. This where it gets weird for me. I tried to simulate connection failure by disabling the internet adapter of the server.

The result is:

the page stops parsing everything after the `$data = curl_exec($curl);`This includes the footer and everything after that line. I knew it because I tried to put echoes before and after `curl_exec` and it really stops there. therefore I cannot catch the error itself.

**What have I tried?**

I tried

- PHP `curl_error()` - which didn't really help since the script stops at `curl_exec`
- PHP `curl_errno()` - same
- try and catch - This should have catch the error but it didn't which frustrates me even more.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a connection timeout?

Comment: I haven't tried it for the reason that I cannot rely on it since there will be times that there is a connection but really slow because it tries to send large JSON data

Comment: Have you tried a try-catch or turning on the error logging?

Comment: Curl has separate timeout and connection timeout options. Specifying a connection timeout should not cause any problems for large file transfers.

Also, is your php installation set up to print or log errors? Does anythign show up there?

Comment: ok the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` did it but I don't know if it will work for all scenarios.. best guess is curl_exec is waiting indefinitely then I hit the php time_out which is weird, I should have time out exceed error in my php if this is the case. I should have figure it out.